# Passing retrofit response to another activity

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am receiving a json server response which I am assigning to an int. I am passing this int to the next activity using putExtra (also tried shared preferences). When I load the next activity the int isnt displaying on screen first time. I have to press the back button and then load the activity again for the int value to be displayed. I cannot figure out why the value isnt passing correctly first time and why on earth it passes successfully on the second reload. Totally baffled by this, I figured it would either pass or fail not fail 1st time and pass on a reload every single time.

The first activity does an insert and captures a row id, passes the row id to the second activity which is used to do an update using the passed row id.

Please see code snippets for context.

FIRST ACTIVITY WITH RETROFIT CALL:

```
case R.id.nextBtnMoodPage:
            if (hasSelected) {

                moodPreferences();
                backgroundSelector();

                Call<ReadCbtId> call = RetrofitClient
                        .getInstance()
                        .getApi()
                        .insertLog(userId, therapistId, moodBefore, automaticThoughtString, distortions, challengeThoughtString, alternativeThoughtString, moodAfter, posted);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<ReadCbtId>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ReadCbtId> call, Response<ReadCbtId> response) {

                        cbtId = response.body().getCbtId();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(cbtId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ReadCbtId> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                //editorWorkout.putInt("cbtId", cbtId);
                //editorWorkout.commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WorkoutAutomaticThoughtActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("cbtId", cbtId);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
```

SECOND ACTIVITY :

```
 /**
 * Ints which are used to store numeric values related to the workout activity.
 */
private int userId, therapistId, cbtId;

private TextView title;

/**
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout_automatic_thought);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    cbtId = extras.getInt("cbtId");

    getSharedPreferences();
    moodPreferences();
    backgroundSelector();
    initialiseViews();
    setListeners();
}

/**
 * Method which gets the users shared preferences. loginPref stores the users ID and workoutPref stores the users mood
 * which they selected at the beginning of the Workout Activity.
 */
private void getSharedPreferences() {

    // Shared preferences track which mood the user selected
    loginPref = getSharedPreferences("loginPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    workoutPref = getSharedPreferences("workoutPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Users login preferences logged from the login activity.
    userId = loginPref.getInt("userId", 0);
    therapistId = loginPref.getInt("therapistId", 0);
   // cbtId = workoutPref.getInt("cbtId", 0);
}

/**
 *
 */
private void initialiseViews() {

    // Initialising editText form the xml file
    automaticThoughtET = findViewById(R.id.automaticThoughtInput);

    // Initialising the nextButton form the xml file
    nextButton = findViewById(R.id.DistortedNextBtn);

    title = findViewById(R.id.automaticThoughtTitle);
    title.setText("Test" + cbtId);

}


 private void setListeners() {
    // Setting an onClick listener to the nextButton
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        /**
         * Method which opens a new activity when the next nextButton is clicked. This method also passed variables through
         * to the next activity as a string.
         * @param v
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!validateText()) {
                return;
            }

            Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient
                    .getInstance()
                    .getApi()
                    .updateAutomaticThought(cbtId, automaticThoughtString);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
            //  Creating a new intent to move from the WorkoutAutomaticThoughtActivity to the WorkoutDistortedThoughtsActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(WorkoutAutomaticThoughtActivity.this, WorkoutDistortedThoughtsActivity.class);

          /*  // Passing variables as Strings to the next activity
            automaticThoughtString = automaticThoughtET.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("AthoughtKey", automaticThoughtString);*/
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the next activity BEFORE you get the result.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WorkoutAutomaticThoughtActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("cbtId", cbtId);
startActivity(intent);
```

This code should be called inside the

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(Call<ReadCbtId> call, Response<ReadCbtId> response) {
    cbtId = response.body().getCbtId();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(cbtId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

So it would look like this:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ReadCbtId> call, Response<ReadCbtId> response) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WorkoutAutomaticThoughtActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("cbtId", response.body().getCbtId());

    Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(response.body().getCbtId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    startActivity(intent);

}
```